# get the id of selected datatable row and pass it through a function for multiple row deletion

Tags: javascript, datatable

I got this code that does almost what I want it to

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
    var table=$('#dataTable').DataTable();
    $('#dataTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
    );
    $('#button').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected');
    }
    );
}

);
</script>
<button type="button" id="button">select all</button>
```

It shows in alert(); how many rows are selected. but what I want it to do is to get the id in the first column of table and pass it through this function for deletion

```
function confirmRemove(id) {
    if (id) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "product-delete.php", type: "post", data: {
                id_delete: id
            }
            , success:function(response) {
                var productTable=$("#dataTable").DataTable();
                productTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                swal( {
                    title: "SUCCESS!", text: "Product Deleted!", icon: "success", timer: 1800, button: false,
                }
                );
            }
            , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        }
        );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the `selected` datatable rows and get first column and pass that to your `confirmRemove` function. Below code does that :

```
$('#button').click(function () {

     var data = table.rows('.selected').data();
     data.each(function (value, index) {
     //call the delete function
     confirmRemove(value[0]);
     });
}
```